# Dynamic Angular.js menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to build a dynamic menu using anuglar.js and bootstrap. This menu needs to have a dropdown ability. I've gotten the basic menu down but now I'm trying to add a dropdown link and I can't get the options to generate correctly.

I have a variable with the menu items like so:

```
var nav = [

    {
        display: 'Home', 
        link: '#/',
        drop: false,
    },
    {
        display: 'Categories', 
        link: '#/', 
        drop: true,
        sub: [
            {
                display: 'Sub 1',
                link: '#/'
            },
            {
                display: 'Sub 2',
                link: '#/'
            },
            {
                display: 'Sub 3',
                link: '#/'
            }
        ]
    }

];
```

I want a dropdown menu to generate of the `sub` items when `drop` is `true` and just a regular menu item when it is `false`.

This is my HTML so far:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="nav in nav" ng-if="drop == nav.drop">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{nav.link}}">
        {{nav.display}}
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="sub in nav.sub"><a href="{{sub.link}}">{{sub.display}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="drop != nav.drop" ng-repeat="nav in nav">
      <a href="{{nav.link}}">{{nav.display}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Right now everything is generating as a normal link.

Comment: ng-repeat="nav in nav" is confusing, can you choose a different name and add a plnkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `ng-if` is the problem. Change this:

```
ng-if="drop == nav.drop"
```

to this:

```
ng-if="nav.drop"
```

and this:

```
ng-if="drop != nav.drop"
```

to this:

```
ng-if="!nav.drop"
```

Incidentally, I agree with the commenter that `ng-repeat="nav in nav"` is confusing.

EDIT:

How to get one list instead of two:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="nav in nav">
    <a ng-if="!nav.drop" href="{{nav.link}}">{{nav.display}}</a>        
    <a ng-if="nav.drop" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{nav.link}}">
      {{nav.display}}
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul ng-if="nav.drop" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="sub in nav.sub"><a href="{{sub.link}}">{{sub.display}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now my non-drop links display before my dropdown links regardless the order in `app.js`. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the content flashes in? Try `class="ng-cloak"` to hide content until angular is ready.

Comment: Going from the top to the bottom of my nav variable. That is how I want the navigation to display left to right on my navbar. But right now the non-drop links show up first and then the drop links from left to right regardless of the order in the variable from top to bottom.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just put your "ng-if" _inside_ your "ng-repeat." Right now you've got two different ng-repeats, so it's building two separate navs, one for drop and one for non-drop. It's probably too much to do in a comment. I'll edit the response to show you what I mean.